# Strange highlighting on navigation

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I'm working on changes for a website that was built by someone who worked here long before I started - one of the changes is to "remove the orange box around the navigation links". It seems that that navigation is created by some JavaScript, so I'm finding it hard to work out how to fix it.

Nothing I can find explains why this would be happening - I'm pretty sure it's not a CSS effect as it's different in each browser (shows up as an orange glow in Chrome, shows up as a dotted outline in IE).

The website is : http://bhealthy.net.au/ and the navigation I am referring to is near the bottom (Home, The Person, The Doctor, etc).

Any help on removing this effect would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the [`outline`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#dynamic-outlines), you can turn it off with this in your stylesheet:

```
* { outline: none; }
```

I'd recommend that you use a more specific selector though, you probably want to leave the `outline` on some things (such as form controls) to enhance usability.

Comment: @Marty: Please check my update, you probably want to use a more specific selector in your CSS than `*`, the `outline` property does have uses that you might want to leave alone.